# Post variables with ajax won't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

I have some data, processed with javascript that I want to write to a database. So I'm trying to code something with ajax. But with no luck...

What I need: I have two variables (id, naam) that I want to pass to a php-script. Nothing more...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function geefNaam(id, naam)
{
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "schrijfrecord.php",
  data: { id: id, naam: naam },
  })
}
</script>
```

and I call this function...

```
geefNaam(id, naam);
```

my php

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$naam = $_POST['naam'];

echo $id;
echo $naam;
?>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and what does happen?

Comment: In particular, there's nothing wrong here, other than a lacking `success:function(){}` call in your `$.ajax()` to do something with the echo'd response

Comment: When you debug this... Is the AJAX call made?  Are the values present in the request?  Are they what you expect them to be?  What is the server's response?  There is critical debug information that you can get here which we can't get for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! For some reason my function isn't called in the code...

Comment: and now it's working, i forgot to include jquery.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `,` after `data: { id: id, naam: naam },`. Also you aren't doing anything after your `$.ajax` call. Use `success: function(){}` or `.done()`. I would use `$.post()`:

```
//<![CDATA[
<script type='text/javascript'>
function geefNaam(id, naam, where){
    $.post('schrijfrecord.php', {id: id, naam: naam},
      function(result){
        where.html(result);
      }
    });
}
$('#someElement').click(function(){
  geefNaam('someId', 'someName', $('#wherever'));
});
//]]>
</script>
```